# What is the inverse of "guardian"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

If I am your guardian, what does that make you to me?

Comment: “Daily Mail” perhaps?

Comment: Inverse? I think you mean "complement". The "inverse" of a guardian would be something like "stalker".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your [dependent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dependent) or [ward](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ward) (credit to [amcnabb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/60505/10041)), both of which are legal entities, but both of which apply outside the legal sphere.

*Dependent* connotes a relationship in which the guardian is both provider and protector, whereas *ward* implies that the guardian is the protector, but not much else.

Comment: Ward is the one I was looking for, that I have read in books.

Answer (score 20):

I like *[charge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge)*:

> : a person or thing committed to the care of another

from [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/charge):

> The scope of someone's responsibility.
>
> ```
> The child was in the nanny's charge.
> ```

Answer (score 19):

A traditional word for this would be "ward" (for example, in Dicken's Bleak House).

Comment: The first example that occurs to me is Dick Grayson, aka Robin, who was always called Bruce Wayne's, aka Batman's, "ward" in the old comic books.